# I can't build Nativescript application (Android) due to gradle memory issue.

Tags: android, gradle, vue.js, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I started using NativeScript-Vue framework, I installed all the requirements 
but when I try to run the application with `tns run android` I get this error: 
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx16384M
The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size.

I would like to precise my laptop has only 8GB of RAM.

I even tried to use lower memory values by setting _JAVA_OPTIONS & GRADLE_OPTS to 
-Xmx1024m but I get the message error with same 'Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx16384M'

I think I am missing some config file which it override the system environment variable or `tns run android` is configured to use 16GB of memory

Also I noticed the `tns run android` command download gradle 4.4 even there's 4.9 is installed.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Can you use grep or similar to search all of the files to work out where the Xmx16384M is coming from?

Comment: thank you I have found the file it was at platforms/android/gradle.properties

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue. My error message was:

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00007fbfa4000000, 536870912, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 536870912 bytes for committing reserved memory.
```

gradle file was in a same place: platform/android/gradle.properties

I changed the file like this:

```
#org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx16384M 
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096
```

And it worked!